# How can I manage the temperature in a heat gun without heat control during desoldering a WSON8 chip?

Tags: soldering

Due to financial constraints I am thinking of buying a cheap heat gun for desoldering.

Usually, cheap heat guns reach high temperatures without too much control.

So how I can avoid burning the chips and have some temperature control when desoldering?

Can this be done by placing the heatgun further away from the board with a small nozzle? Also, what other measures I can take to avoid overheating?

Comment: Yes, you can use heat-gun, any distance, but be careful, no secret, all takes is practice, like riding a bike, especially while you don't have any options but a hairdryer. I had to solder using a metal chopstick and charcoal, to solder my first radio.

Comment: you can make a tin foil mask to shield the components that need to stay cool.

Comment: But also how I can controll the temperature over the component that I need to apply heat but not overheat it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, controlling the distance to the board is the best approach. As @jay said, it takes practice.

Since you only get control over two variables (heat on time and distance to board) then using a further distance will take longer to heat up the board. This is good, since it gives you more time to notice the solder has become liquid, before reaching too much heat to cause damage. But too far will cause more area of the board to heat up, not only making it difficult to hold but also will melt solder on parts you didn't want to remove.

The best approach is to use a far distance at first, get the main board area of interest close to melting point, then move to a shorter distance and quickly unsolder the targeted part. Have tweezers on hand and constantly testing the part with a little pressure.

Also, you must be sure the backside of the board at the target site doesn't have parts, or they can fall off as you heat up the front side.

Additionally, you want to inspect the area for soft plastic parts such as connector body. Those will typically get too hot and scorch. You want to direct the flow of air away from those, or as @dandais suggested use some foil to protect them. Just cut some aluminum foil from the kitchen to size and tape it down with high temp tape [such as this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HFN67OS).

Comment: "But too far will cause more area of the board to heat up" ... which is actually a good thing, if you want to avoid warping and later stress failures. That is why it is important to warm entire board evenly just under melting point, before pushing it above melting point locally